# DocuSign API - Set Size of Text Tab Input

Tags: docusignapi

I'm generating an envelope via the DocuSign API which includes 2 text tabs - these are appearing successfully, but the size of the text input is very small to start with. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Is there a way I can make this wider to start with, preferably the same width as the line that it appears on? Here's the JSON for the text tab that I'm generating currently:

```
    "textTabs" : 
    [
        {
            "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
            "anchorString" : "/SigName1/",
            "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
            "anchorXOffset" : "0",
            "anchorYOffset" : "0",
            "documentId" : "1",
            "locked" : "false",
            "name" : "Your Full Name",
            "pageNumber" : "",
            "tabLabel" : "Your Full Name",
            "value" : ""
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"textTabs" : 
[
    {
        "anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent" : false,
        "anchorString" : "/SigName1/",
        "anchorUnits" : "pixels",
        "anchorXOffset" : "0",
        "anchorYOffset" : "0",
        "width" : "176",
        "height": "125",
        "documentId" : "1",
        "locked" : "false",
        "name" : "Your Full Name",
        "pageNumber" : "",
        "tabLabel" : "Your Full Name",
        "value" : ""
    },
```

Comment: Thanks - I gather from testing that if I specify the width and height that this limits the amount of text the signer can enter into the text field here to the size of the field specified by the height/width values?

Comment: If this answered your question, would you mind marking this question as "answered" ?thanks!

Comment: Thanks - just to clarify it appears to limit the amount of text that can be entered into the text field/tab, not just what is visible? Is there a way to have a pre-set width that doesn't have the limit and allows the user to enter text beyond the initial width of the text tab?

Comment: no. The reason is this is a PDF that is "etched" and only visible text will be visible in the final signed document.